# How the dynamic data in a page which is rendered from database are cached in search engines?

Tags: asp.net, .net, seo, search-engine, google-search

How the dynamic data in a page which is rendered from database are cached in Search Engines like Google, Yahoo or Bing?

If I create a ASP.NET website with a GRID or some other control which fetches the data from SQL database. I am not sure how the a search engine would cache such data in their servers?

I am sure that if there is any physical .html file in the web-hosting directory with relevant settings the search engines would parse/crawl it successfully. But not sure about the dynamic data.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic data in a page which is rendered from database are still HTML for Browsers and Crawlers. So basically crawlers catch whatever it finds in source code.. including CSS, Java scripts.

Comment: Thanks Suri, I have another doubt in same scenario , say there is a button in a asp.net page so the data will not get rendered until it is clicked. Just want to know in this case how the search crawl works ?

Comment: May.. May not. Search Engines also do experiment with onclick events sometimes. But we cant say clearly. Best way is to TEST. But don't forget to give some time to index your pages. Have patience while testing.